# Webpacker asset digest not consistent from deploy to deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I'm using Rails with Webpacker. When I deploy, my CSS asset digest (the digest on the files in `public/packs/css`) is not the same from deploy to deploy.

Not only is the digest not the same from deploy to deploy, but sometimes (although not always) the digest is different from machine to machine.

How can I troubleshoot this issue? I thought I could maybe gain some insight by learning exactly how the digest is generated, but I haven't been able to find any good information on that so far.

Comment: Webpack hashing is stable, but what it gets fed is not. To debug, review this issue https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7179#issuecomment-547557053

Comment: What version of Webpacker are you using?

Comment: @rossta Webpacker 5.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution, thanks to [these](https://github.com/ackama/rails-template/issues/217) [two](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/2003) GitHub issues.

Step 1: run `yarn add webpack-merge`.

Step 2: change `config/webpack/environment.js` to match the following:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');

const sassLoader = environment.loaders.get('sass')
const cssLoader = environment.loaders.get('css')

sassLoader.use.map(loader => {
  if (loader.loader === 'css-loader') {
    loader.options = merge(loader.options, { sourceMap: false })
  }
});

cssLoader.use.map(loader => {
  if (loader.loader === 'css-loader') {
    loader.options = merge(loader.options, { sourceMap: false })
  }
});

module.exports = environment
```

Afterward, the CSS digests should be deterministic.